# STSPIN32f0 - does anyone have experience?

Tags: pwm, stm32, stm32f0

I'm trying to write custom firmware for [STSPIN32f0](http://www.st.com/en/motor-drivers/stspin32f0.html) and I'm desperately stuck
STSPIN32f0 is a system-in-package based on STM32F031C6.
My code works fine on STM32F031C6. 
My code fails miserably both on my custom board and on [STEVAL-SPIN3201](http://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/steval-spin3201.html).
What I'm trying to achieve is pretty simple: I configure TIM1 in 6-PWM mode. On STM32F031C6 I can see 6 signals exactly as expected, on STSPIN32f0 I can see nothing.

Does anyone have experience with STSPIN32f0 please? Can anyone please give me any hint(s)? Can anyone please share their working code samples?

---

This is my code:

```
//

int main(void)
{
    //

    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN |                 // enable clock for GPIOA
                   RCC_AHBENR_GPIOBEN;                  // enable clock for GPIOB

    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM2EN;                 // enable timer 2
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_TIM1EN;                 // enable timer 1

    TIM1->ARR = 0xA0;                                   // tim1 period

    // over-current config (pin A-11)

    GPIOA->MODER |= (0x01 << GPIO_MODER_MODER11_Pos);       // output
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= (0x01 << GPIO_OSPEEDR_OSPEEDR11_Pos); // medium speed
    GPIOA->PUPDR |= (0x01 << GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR11_Pos);       // pull-up
    GPIOA->ODR &= ~(1 << 11);                               // set zero

    //

    TIM1->CCMR1 |= TIM_CCMR1_OC1PE |                    // Output compare on channel 1 preload enable (for pin B-13, low-side 1)
                   (0x06 << TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_Pos) |       // Output compare on channel 1 mode = 110 (PWM mode 1)
                   TIM_CCMR1_OC2PE |                    // Output compare on channel 2 preload enable (for pin B-14, low-side 2)
                   (0x06 << TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_Pos);        // Output compare on channel 2 mode = 110 (PWM mode 1)

    TIM1->CCMR2 |= TIM_CCMR2_OC3PE |                    // Output compare channel 3 preload enable (for pin A-10, high-side and pin B-15, low-side)
                   (0x06 << TIM_CCMR2_OC3M_Pos);        // Output compare 3 mode = 110 (PWM mode 1)

    GPIOA->MODER |= (0x02 << GPIO_MODER_MODER8_Pos) |   // alternative function for pin A-8 (pwm channel 1, positive)
                    (0x02 << GPIO_MODER_MODER9_Pos) |   // alternative function for pin A-9 (pwm channel 2, positive)
                    (0x02 << GPIO_MODER_MODER10_Pos);   // alternative function for pin A-10 (pwm channel 3, positive)

    GPIOB->MODER |= (0x02 << GPIO_MODER_MODER13_Pos) |  // alternate function for pin B-13 (PWM channel 1, negative)
                    (0x02 << GPIO_MODER_MODER14_Pos) |  // alternate function for pin B-14 (PWM channel 2, negative)
                    (0x02 << GPIO_MODER_MODER15_Pos);   // alternate function for pin B-15 (PWM channel 3, negative)

    GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= GPIO_OSPEEDR_OSPEEDR8 |           // high speed for pin A-8 (pwm channel 1, positive)
                      GPIO_OSPEEDR_OSPEEDR9 |           // high speed for pin A-9 (pwm channel 2, positive)
                      GPIO_OSPEEDR_OSPEEDR10;           // high speed for pin A-10 (pwm channel 3, positive)

    GPIOB->OSPEEDR |= GPIO_OSPEEDR_OSPEEDR13 |          // high speed for pin B-13 (pwm channel 1, negative)
                      GPIO_OSPEEDR_OSPEEDR14 |          // high speed for pin B-14 (pwm channel 2, negative)
                      GPIO_OSPEEDR_OSPEEDR15;           // high speed for pin B-15 (pwm channel 3, negative)

    GPIOA->AFR[1] |= (0x02 << GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL8_Pos) |   // for pin A-8 alternative funciton 2
                     (0x02 << GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL9_Pos) |   // for pin A-9 alternative funciton 2
                     (0x02 << GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL10_Pos);   // for pin A-10 alternative funciton 2

    GPIOB->AFR[1] |= (0x02 << GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL13_Pos) |  // for pin B-13 alternative funciton 2
                     (0x02 << GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL14_Pos) |  // for pin B-14 alternative funciton 2
                     (0x02 << GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL15_Pos);   // for pin B-15 alternative funciton 2

    TIM1->CCR3 = 0xA;                           // duty cycle of tim1 channel 3
    TIM1->CCR2 = 0xA;                           // duty cycle of tim1 channel 2
    TIM1->CCR1 = 0xA;                           // duty cycle of tim1 channel 1

    TIM1->CR1 |= (0x01 << TIM_CR1_CMS_Pos);     // centre-aligned mode 1 - up&down

    TIM1->RCR = 0x3;                            // repetition counter
    TIM1->BDTR |= TIM_BDTR_MOE |                // main output enable
                  TIM_BDTR_OSSR |               // Off-state selection for Run mode
                  TIM_BDTR_OSSI |               // Off-state selection for Idle mode
                  0x02;                         // 2-count dead-time


    TIM1->CR1 |= TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE; // enable timer 1 preload

    TIM1->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1E |               // enable channel 1, positive
                  TIM_CCER_CC2E |               // enable channel 2, positive
                  TIM_CCER_CC3E |               // enable channel 3, positive

                  TIM_CCER_CC1NE |              // enable channel 1, negative
                  TIM_CCER_CC2NE |              // enable channel 2, negative
                  TIM_CCER_CC3NE;               // enable channel 3, negative

    TIM1->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;                    // force update event

    TIM1->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN; // enable timer 1

    while (1)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something easier - single channel, simple gpio etc etc. to play a bit with the new hardware?

Comment: Peter, thank you very much for your encouragement, yes I did. I tried single channel PWM driving LED and it worked fine. Also, my code works on stand-alone processor, but not on system-in-module. This is the thing that drives me crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently prototyping on this EVB. Please configure GPIOF and set the PF6 and PF7 pins to different state than 0, as it forces the VREG and driver part into standby mode. This is described in chapter 6.4 of STSPIN32F0 datasheet, page 23.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is actually correct. Same answer was given me by ST support in this thread:
https://community.st.com/message/166790?commentID=166790